# SQL query for retrieving different data series contained in the same table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve data series contained in a table that basically looks like this:

```
row | timestamp | seriesId | int32 | int64 | double
---------------------------------------------------
  0 |         0 |        0 |     2 |       |
  1 |         1 |        0 |     4 |       |
  2 |         1 |        1 |   435 |       |
  3 |         1 |        2 |       |  2345 |
  4 |         1 |        3 |       |       |    0.5
  5 |         2 |        0 |     5 |       |
  6 |         2 |        1 |   453 |       |
  7 |         2 |        2 |       |  2401 |
  ....
```

I would like to get a result set that looks like this (so that I can easily plot it):

```
row | timestamp | series0 | series1 | series 2 | ...
----------------------------------------------------
  0 |         0 |       2 |         |          |
  1 |         1 |       4 |     435 |     2345 |
  2 |         2 |       5 |     453 |     2401 |
...
```

My SQL skillz are unfortunately not really what they should be, so my first attempt at achieving this feels a bit awkward:

```
SELECT tbl0.timestamp, tbl0.int32 as series0,
       tbl1.int32 as series1
FROM
      (SELECT * FROM StreamData WHERE seriesId=0) as tbl0
    INNER JOIN
      (SELECT * FROM StreamData WHERE seriesId=1) as tbl1
    ON tbl0.timestamp = tbl1.timestamp
ORDER BY tbl0.timestamp;
```

This doesn't really seem to be the right way of trying to accomplish this, especially not when the number of different series goes up. I can change the way data gets stored in the table (it's in an SQLite database if that matters) if that would make things easier, but as the number of different series may be different from time to time, I would prefer having them all in the same table.

**Is there a better way to write the above query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only work if you know how many series you have stored in there.  So compacting INT32, INT64 and DOUBLE down will work fine.  But as you can have any number of SeriesID's, there's a problem there.

Here's how to compact the nullable columns (ignoring the existance of SeriesID).

```
SELECT
  timestamp,
  MAX(int32)             AS series0,
  MAX(int64)             AS series1,
  MAX(double)            AS series2
FROM
  StreamData
GROUP BY
  timestamp
```

If you know the exact number of series, you could modify it as follows...

```
SELECT
  timestamp,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seriesID = 0 THEN int32  ELSE NULL END)             AS series0,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seriesID = 1 THEN int64  ELSE NULL END)             AS series1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seriesID = 2 THEN double ELSE NULL END)             AS series2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seriesID = 3 THEN int32  ELSE NULL END)             AS series3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seriesID = 4 THEN int64  ELSE NULL END)             AS series4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seriesID = 5 THEN double ELSE NULL END)             AS series5
FROM
  StreamData
GROUP BY
  timestamp
```

But if you want the SQL to work all of this out itself, for any number of series.  You'd have to write code that writes the SQL you need.

Comment: I chose to accept this answer although all answers seem to have used basically the same approach to solving this. This was simply the query code that matched best.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have to use "group by":

```
SELECT row, timestamp, count(seriedIS) AS series0, sum(int32) AS series1, sum(int64) AS series2
FROM StreamData
WHERE (streamId=0) OR (streamId=1)
GROUP BY (timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

Just try!

Comment: This does not produce the output that the OP wants.

Comment: Does SQLite really let you select `row` without grouping by it?

Comment: I'm grouping by timestamp.. :S

Comment: Yes, I know you are.  But you're also SELECTing the `row` field, *without* grouping by that.  Which is why I ask if SQLite really allows that.

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand! Yep, sqlite allows that but write a random row-value! Actually, it's no important selecting "row" column!

Comment: +1 for being first with identifying that it was the GROUP BY clause I had missed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a potentially variable number of `seriesId`, you will need to assemble the SQL Query dynamically. It would have to look like this:

```
select 
    TimeStamp,
    Max(case seriesId when 0 then coalesce(int32, int64) else null end) series0,
    Max(case seriesId when 1 then coalesce(int32, int64) else null end) series1,
    Max(case seriesId when 2 then coalesce(int32, int64) else null end) series2,
    Max(case seriesId when 3 then coalesce(int32, int64) else null end) series3,
    Max(case seriesId when 4 then coalesce(int32, int64) else null end) series4,
    Max(case seriesId when 5 then coalesce(int32, int64) else null end) series5,
    Max(case seriesId when 6 then coalesce(int32, int64) else null end) series6
from StreamData 
group by TimeStamp
order by TimeStamp
```

Also from your data sample, I understood that you get either `int32` or `int64`, depending on `int32` nullity, thus, the `coalesce`.

Comment: What about the double dolumn?  Perhaps, if you want to use the coalesce approach you want something like...  `COALESCE([double], CAST([int64] AS DOUBLE), CAST([int32] AS DOUBLE))`

Comment: +1 for giving a good answer, I probably do not need the coalesce() function though, so Dems' answer got accepted.